# Run the application from its EAR

Tags: oracle-adf, weblogic11g

I have only ear file of the application and I need to deploy it on the server. I tried deploying it directly on my integrated weblogic server but because of security in the EAR, it is asking username/password from me and when I provide one from jazn file of the application, it does not accept.

Next I tried  creating customization application of the ear and there I gave reference to jazn file while creating project. Now it is accepting my password but while running, it is throwing error -

> [oracle.jbo.NoDefException][oracle.jbo.mom.DefinitionManager.findDefinitionObject][ApplicationCustomer]

I googled this error but  seems like it is because it is not able to find business components from the corresponding model project. I added the model project as a dependency but still getting the same error.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own users directly in Weblogic, though Weblogic Console:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E21764_01/apirefs.1111/e13952/taskhelp/security/DefineUsers.html

Since users are server specific and not application specific, you can use these users to log on against your application.

For convenience reasons an ADF application can deploy users and roles, but thats only for testing purposes. In Production systems, users are not being deployed with the application, but either created through Weblogic Console or  Enterprise Manager, or 'injected' by a Authentication Provider.

Comment: I tried this but now although authentication is successful but it fails authorization. Throwing 401-Unauthorized error

Comment: This means you also need to create certain Enterprise Groups and assign them to your user. To know exactly what enterprise groups you need to create,  you can unzip the EAR file and check jazn-data.xml, more precisely Enterprise Roles - Users mappings. Then you can mirror the same users and enterprise roles from Weblogic Console.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to change passwords for the users deployed along with the application. On Weblogic Console, go to:

Security Realms -> My realm -> User and Groups -> select one of the users -> Passwords.

Then provide New Password and Confirm New Password fields. Save.

Comment: west007, if you don't mind me asking, can you please update this post with what are your conclusions? You can mark the response as helpful if it brought any help, or you can further post feedback on what went wrong. Is the least we can do, when people use their own time answering questions.